# How do I do signal comparison without using opamp?

Tags: comparator

I want to remove the opamp IC seen in the schematic below with the least number of transistors possible in order to simplify the circuit, reduce cost and increase switching performance when used with high frequency input.

The new comparator must give digital output unlike the standard difference amplifier circuit does.

How do I do this replacement?

[image]

This will be a bridge rectifier circuit done with MOSFETs. *Dir1* is supposed to be logic-high only when \$V_{ac}>0\$. And, *Dir2* must be logic-high only when \$V_{ac}<0\$. *VCC1* is isolated from the AC grid.

Comment: ICs are popular because they perform better and are cheaper than the discrete alternatives, so your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Phil is correct, stick with using IC's. You will not save any money or size. In fact it will be just the opposite as you will spend more time on design and use much more board space.

Comment: Use a comparator. Opamps make bad comparators.

Comment: A simple 2 transistor Schmitt trigger, sharing the same emitter resistance but different collector current. Threshold voltage will be one diode voltage drop. See here http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/electron/elect18.htm

Comment: Sometimes you can save money (BOM cost) by getting rid of op-amps and replacing them with discrete circuitry. Usually the discrete solution will take up more board space. But if you need high-speed switching, I think you will be better off, both in terms of cost and board space, using a comparator as Nick said.

Comment: @MisterTea, if the anticipated production volume is high, the time spent reducing BOM cost will be well worth it, assuming it succeeds. This project could be one of those deals where the design is reviewed prior to year 2 of production to try to achieve cost improvements. (A cost improvement project, CIP). Although I think it would be better to qualify multiple parts for the socket, and then go after cost cuts with the suppliers rather than implement a discrete design.